# How to get the power of a Double with another Double in Swift 5.5?

Tags: swift, double, swift5

So long story short I need to get **x** to the power of **y** which are both doubles

Problem is I keep getting 0

```
import Darwin

x: Double = 3.86
y: Double = 4.86

var Answer = Int(pow(Double(x),Double(y))) 

// Answer = 0?
// Answer Should = 709.2744...
```

So why is this the case and how do I make this actually work?

and yes this calculation works fine with Integers just the second Doubles get added to the mix it just all falls apart

Comment: @JoakimDanielson where did you read that? `y` needs to be an `Int` only if `x` is `Decimal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x: Double = 3.86
var y: Double = 4.86

var Answer = Double(pow(x, y)) 

print(Answer)
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you also need to import Foundation